# Enum class to string

Tags: string, switch-statement, alternate, enum-class

I’m having a solution with switch cases but there are many cases so clang-tidy is giving warning for that function. My motive is to decrease the size of function. Is there any way that we can do to decrease size of function.

Answer (score 0):

As **enum class** can be used as key for **std::map**, You can use the map to keep relation of enum <-> string, like this:

```
enum class test_enum { first, second, third };

const char* to_string(test_enum val) {
    static const std::map<test_enum,const char*> dict = {
        { test_enum::first, "first" },
        { test_enum::second, "second" },
        { test_enum::third, "third" }
    };
    
    auto tmp = dict.find(val);
    return (tmp != dict.end()) ? tmp->second : "<unknown>";
}
```

C++ has no reflection, so map cannot be filled automatically; however, using compiler-specific extensions (e.g. like **__PRETTY_FUNCTION__** extension for GCC) it can be done, e.g. like in [magic_enum library](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum)